# have carousel with three columns in angular js

Tags: angularjs, carousel

Good day,
I have a carousel. i need to loop in and show 3 columns on each iteration. 
basically, on the example below, i have set of images. i need to show three images each time with their information.
so shows 1 2 3 then 4 5 6 then 7 8 ... so each iteration is set of 3 images

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 5000;
  var slides = $scope.slides = [];
  $scope.addSlide = function() {
    var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
    slides.push({
      image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
      text: ['More','Extra','Lots of','Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
        ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
    });
  };
  for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    $scope.addSlide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
  <div style="height: 305px">
    <carousel interval="myInterval">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
        <div class=row>
          <div class=col-xs-4>
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
              <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=col-xs-4>
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
              <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class=col-xs-4>
            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide {{$index+2}}</h4>
              <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addSlide()">Add Slide</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Interval, in milliseconds: <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="myInterval">
      <br />Enter a negative number or 0 to stop the interval.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: let's say we have an array of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]                                 the concern is i would like to show my data on each iteration like 1 2 3, then next iteration 4 5 6 ... 7 8 9  ...

Comment: i got this lib http://getuikit.com/docs/slideset.html but i need to give it a trail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 5000;
  var slides = $scope.slides = [];
  $scope.addSlide = function() {
    var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
    slides.push({
      image: 'http://placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
      text: ['More', 'Extra', 'Lots of', 'Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' + ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
    });
  };


var currentIndex = 0;
// this is really ugly. don't try this at home, kids.
setTimeout(function () {
    var directiveScope = angular.element(document.querySelector('.carousel-inner')).scope();
    directiveScope.next = function() {
        var newIndex = (currentIndex + 3) % directiveScope.slides.length;
        currentIndex = newIndex;

        //Prevent this user-triggered transition from occurring if there is already one in progress
        if (!directiveScope.$currentTransition) {
            return directiveScope.select(directiveScope.slides[newIndex], 'next');
        }
    };
}, 100);
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $scope.addSlide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
    <div style="height: 305px">
      <carousel interval="myInterval">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
          <div class=row>
            <div class=col-xs-4>
              <img ng-src="{{slides[$index].image}}" style="margin:auto;">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
                <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class=col-xs-4>
              <img ng-src="{{slides[$index+1].image}}" style="margin:auto;">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
                <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class=col-xs-4>
              <img ng-src="{{slides[$index+2].image}}" style="margin:auto;">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Slide {{$index+2}}</h4>
                <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </slide>
      </carousel>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addSlide()">Add Slide</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        Interval, in milliseconds:
        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="myInterval">
        <br />Enter a negative number or 0 to stop the interval.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the problem is that now is showing 1,2,3 then 2,3,4, .... on the 2nd iteration i need it to start from 4 not 2 ... thanks for your input

Comment: @MohammedAl-Hanabi, couldn't find a better way to do it. their directive is not really designed to be extended in any way.

Comment: thanks for your support. are you aware of any directive that is capable to do this approach? @ilj

Comment: please accept the answer if it works for you. googling for "angularjs carousel" shows a few more implementations - try playing with them.

Comment: still, i am looking for a correct answer. i need to change the iteration to 1 then 4 then 7  then 10 .... so ng-repeat="slide in slides" need to iterate every 3.

Comment: @MohammedAl-Hanabi, i edited my snippet. that's exactly what it's doing now!

Comment: :) thank you. I decided that i can create all html needed on the backend then inject the HTML . though, your solution is working fine  regards,